# 404 error when trying to download node.js v0.6.19 to server on webfaction

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the wget command to download node.js to my server on webfaction.

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.6.19.tar.gz
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
--2012-06-06 12:41:40--  http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.6.19.tar.gz
Resolving nodejs.org... 8.12.44.238
Connecting to nodejs.org|8.12.44.238|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-06-06 12:41:40 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I'm not exactly sure why I'm getting the 404 Error, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.6.19.tar.gz` does not exist!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing the same problem, this is the actual source.

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.19/node-v0.6.19.tar.gz
```